# Does the total Zak phase always sum to zero?

Tags: condensed-matter, topology, electronic-band-theory, chern-simons-theory, berry-pancharatnam-phase

In 2D, the sum of the Chern numbers over all bands is zero. However, this result relies on the ability to define a Berry curvature, which is only possible in $d \geq 2$ dimensions. In 1D it is impossible to define a Berry curvature, but does the total Zak phase summed over all bands also have to be zero? There are other instances where the 1D and 2D results differ (e.g., the Chern number is zero in 2D when there is time reversal symmetry, but the same is not true for the Zak phase in 1D).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.